# Using # in anchors for javascript functionality

Tags: javascript, css

Like most things in CSS, there are ways that work, and there are the right ways. Unfortunately, I'm not so much of a CSS guru.

I set '#' I my hrefs for a number of things - for things like opening menus etc.

However, I recently found a need to scroll smoothly to a place on the page. After some investigation, I came up with this code:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".body-wrap").animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 300);
});
```

Nothing wrong with it - it works.

However, it also causes conflict with every other '#' based href on the page that I use for other javascript triggers - specifically `a[href^="#"]`.

The question I have is, is there a better way to approach this that is still as generic? For instance, you might say - don't need to assign # to all hrefs - I'm not sure what the impact might be, or there might be ways of adding to the selector above to make it more specific - such as, starts with #,but has other characters following.

This kind of thing must challenge developers every day, so there must be preferred techniques, or patterns to deal with this cleanly.

Comment: You can change the selector to `a[href^="#"]:not([href="#"])`, which may be a tad slower on IE8 and most browsers. For that, you can use the `.not('[href="#"]')` method or the `.filter(':not([href="#"])')` method. Both should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for everyones answer - chose mplungjan's answer because it is versatile and was first to the pass. However, voted up all other good answers - neilhem, great time for adding "js" to the front of classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preferred solution is to give them a class

```
$(".scrollLink").on("click",function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".body-wrap").animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
  }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The best practice is prefixing javascript specific classes with `js-`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-scroll-link', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.body-wrap').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
  }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want/need to use classes, you can always check if `this.hash` is an empty string before animating. In that case you will need to add empty/invisible `<a id="top"></a>` to the top of your page and set `href` to `#top` for your "smooth scroll links" which are meant to scroll to the top of page.

However using classes is preferable.

Comment: That is a great idea, and it allows to run the function to scroll to the top anyway.  And it can be as easy as using `$(this.hash || document).offset().top` (not recommened) or `this.hash ? $(this.hash).offset().top : 0`